# How to recharge a bootstrap capacitor on an H-bridge with each transistor controlled with a pwm GPIO?

Tags: pwm, h-bridge, programming, mbed, bootstrap

I have built an H-bridge using bootstrap. Each MOSFET is controlled by a PWM output of my µc.

Let's say my motor turns clockwise. I set H1 and L2 to a duty cycle α = 0.9, then to recharge H1's cap I would need to close L1 when H1 is off. So L1 has the duty cycle = (1-α).

I use mbed and there is no easy way to control the timers, compare registers etc. How could I set L1 to be the opposite of H1 if I'm going clockwise?

I thought of using a down-counter but it would need to be perfectly synced to the up-counter - right?

Thank you for your help

Here is my source code.

```
void set_force(float force){
    if(force == 0.0f) {
        L1.write(0.0f);
        H1.write(0.0f);
        L2.write(0.0f);
        H2.write(0.0f);
    } else if (force > 0) {
        L1.write(0.0f);
        H1.write(1.0f); //H1.write(force);
        L2.write(force);
        H2.write(0.0f);
    } else {
        L1.write(1.0f); //L1.write(-1.0f*force)
        H1.write(0.0f);
        L2.write(0.0f);
        H2.write(-1.0f*force);
}}
```

[image: This is how I named my GPIOs]

Comment: @jsotola did you mean "H1 and L2" ?

Comment: Use H 1,2 for direction and L2 or L1  for PWM only to create boost for each H side Nch

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Sorry, it didn't work. because to keep H1 closed we need it's cap charged, and to charge it we need to close L1, so I can't have constantly on

Comment: @jsotola because if I don't pulse H1 then i can't close L1 to charge the capacitor, but if i open H1, then close L1, it will short both of the motor's leads to ground and brake it. (I might be wrong i'm really new to this)

Comment: antoine , you did it wrong.  L2 boosts H1 and L1 boost H2 gate voltage or either diode OR boosts both.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I don't understand what you mean by "boosts", is "to recharge the bootstrap capacitor" ?

Comment: Yes by a C coupled diode negative clamp and low side PWM

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Solved, Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. H1's capacitor **can** charge through the motor if L2 is closed.
Thank you @Tony Stewart EE75 for holding on

```
   void set_force(float force){
        if(force == 0.0f) {
            L1.write(0.0f);
            H1.write(0.0f);
            L2.write(0.0f);
            H2.write(0.0f);
        } else if (force > 0.0f) {
            L1.write(0.0f);
            H1.write(force); // there was "1" here
            L2.write(1.0f); // there was "force" here
            H2.write(0.0f);
        } else {
            L1.write(1.0f);
            H1.write(0.0f);
            L2.write(0.0f);
            H2.write(-1.0f*force);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm that’s a catch 22 to have H1 create  a boost voltage before it can switch to the boost cap above Vdd.